# How can I model the dome in the picture?

Tags: modeling

I have been trying to model this dome but my result looks exaggerated.
I want the bulge out to be subtle as in the picture.[image: Dome Picture]
[image: My approach]

Comment: The main difference for now between the reference and the model base forms is that on the ref bulges come down to one line whereas they are bulged in the bottom of the model.

Comment: Exactly....I am trying to find a way around it,but trying to manipulate the bottom vertices also destroys the shape which is not helpful.